# Crypto-mining maleware that disable input and output devices

Tags: nvidia, freeze, malware, cpu-load, antivirus

I recently find my computer monitor sometimes shuts down itself and cannot be wake up by tying on my keyboard or my mouse. I turned off and on the monitor, but it shows 'no input signal'. I changed the cable and monitor and ended up with the same result. In the meantime, the CPU and GPU were running at full speed, which can be told from the brightness of  LED gaming fan light of my PC. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a NVIDIA 1080ti GPU. I feel my PC is hijacked by a crypto-mining malware, but I can't confirm because the GPU output is shut off by the malware. It happens around 5 times already, and usually it happens when the computer is idle. Only once my was my PC hijacked when I was using it.

I can't find any free anti-virus software that targets crypto-hijacking of Linux system. Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: This sounds like you filled up your ram or suspend fails

Comment: If your system has been compromised, then take it off the network and clean-reinstall. That means erase the disk while you reinstall; any data that is not already backed-up will be erased. Half-measures may leave the malware in place. Using backups from *after* you were infected may restore the malware. You won't find much "anti-virus" beyond ClamAV simply because a clean-reinstall is so easy.